# Headers are removed once new data binds to the original dataframe R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a data to dataframe which was created with some headers.

Code:

```
OutputTable <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0))
x <- c("Desk","Date", "Symbol","Required Time Mtd", "Covered Time Mtd", "Required Time Daily", "Covered Time Daily")
colnames(OutputTable) <- x
OutputTable <- rbind(OutputTable,list("HKCHN","2018-12-12","FMCN5","15:15","15:15","15:15","15:15"))
```

When I do so, I lose the headers. The resulting data frame looks such as this:

```
> OutputTable
  X.HKCHN. X.2018.12.12. X.FMCN5. X.15.15. X.15.15..1 X.15.15..2 X.15.15..3
1    HKCHN    2018-12-12    FMCN5    15:15      15:15      15:15      15:15
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 3):

when using `rbind`, R taken the `df` you've created and sees it's empty, so the column names are taken from the 2nd object passed - whether it's a list or an array. As explained in the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html):

> For cbind (rbind), vectors of zero length (including NULL) are ignored
>   unless the result would have zero rows (columns), for S compatibility.
>   (Zero-extent matrices do not occur in S3 and are not ignored in R.)

the easiest solution would be

```
OutputTable[1, ] <- c("HKCHN","2018-12-12","FMCN5","15:15","15:15","15:15","15:15")
```

which places the desired data in the first row and refrains from any automatic merging and naming methods.

Comment: Nice one. Maybe you colud make it nicer by quoting the help page, section Details: *The rbind data frame method first drops all zero-column and zero-row arguments.*.

Comment: aye aye sir, roger and out